# Is it possible to have a signature that signs itself?

Tags: hash, signature

This is a curiosity. I don't see any value (yet) of using this.

Is it possible to have a signature that signs itself?

What I mean is that when you send a signed message, you send something like $(message \mathbin\| signature)$, where $signature = Sign(message)$. Is there a signature scheme in which $signature = Sign(message \mathbin\| signature)$?

Because the message should be hashed, you can't solve for $signature$ or do some sort of meet-in-the-middle solution.

My initial thoughts are (1) using SHA-2 or some other hash functions vulnerable to a length extension attack or (2) use homomorphic hash in some fashion. (1) would still require brute-force, but it would reduce computation. I haven't figured out how to use (2), especially since all the homomorphic hashes I know about aren't homomorphic w/r/t concatenation.

Comment: There are schemes (Fiat-Shamir Transformed Sigma ZKPs) where you have a signature $(c,z)$, you derive some value $a$ from them and then check whether $c=H(a\|m)$, this is _kinda_ cyclic. [Here's a recent example I wrote up.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81171/23623)

Comment: `Is it possible to have a signature that signs itself?` Aren't we talking about an unborn child?

Comment: I don't think length extension attacks are usable for this. As clearly indicated to me, length extensions are mainly on topic if you hash data & a secret; and I don't see the secret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a signature scheme in which $\text{signature} = \mathsf{Sign}(\text{message} \mathbin\| \text{signature})$ ?

With standard RSA signatures (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, RSASSA-PSS of [PKCS#1](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=27)), that's possible if one chooses the public/private key pair for that purpose, as a function of the message. On top of that one can even make the signature nearly anything (any bytestring the size of the public modulus except two¹: the all-zero bytestring, and its variation with the last byte 0x01).

I'll use [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=31) with RSA-2048 and SHA-256, because that's simple and common. I'll silently assimilate bitstrings to integers per big-endian convention.

Choose our arbitrary message $M$. Choose our 256-byte signature $S$ of 2048-bit, other than 0 or 1, and not overly close to $2^{2048}$ (say, the first byte is not 0xFF). Hash $M\mathbin\|S$ with SHA-256, yielding $H$, and form the 256-byte representative per [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=40)
$$R = \mathtt{00\,01}\,\underbrace{\mathtt{FF…FF}}_{202\text{ bytes}}\,\mathtt{00\,30\,31\,30\,0d\,06\,09\,60\,86\,48\,01\,65\,03\,04\,02\,01\,05\,00\,04\,20}\mathbin\|H$$

There remains to build a public/private RSA key pair $(N,e,d)$ with $N$ of 2048 bits such that $S^e\bmod N=R$ and $S<N$, which will insure that $S=\mathsf{Sign}_{(n,d)}(M\mathbin\|S)=S$, as asked.

The central idea is to choose $N$ the product of two primes $p$ and $q$ such that we can find odd $e_p$ with $S^{e_p}\equiv R\bmod p$ and $e_q$ with $S^{e_q}\equiv R\bmod q$, with $(p-1)/2$ and $(q-1)/2$ coprime, and product of distinct small primes. We'll then find $e$ by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Refer to [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/80322/555) for details.

That takes like 30s in Python, [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7b9s4Ev9fn2LqorBky4nlPNb1xQV6bbpX7KYo4uIOh7QI9KBt1hIlkZLjLPrdezOkXnac3hpwLA05w3n85sFkj8U6FWc/f76E35lg0i8Y@AJuF29hwx4hXcJ0sIGAFwpUCsXaL2ABXOETA8VXwi9KyWjbDfz4gUsZk8S8WLwdff7j3cIbbb37C3jgxRoW/3o7mlxcWhuYA/5C9/MSRJkEyIuSgseCKVimErIyiHkISRqVcangE9jEN3pDJ4wm4/OpY92gsKB3w5TyVwx6lbDEvLvgS1Rd@vLRWuiNi1rlntnYmIBb4yRVRcvhotZxDAGDzI8iFhkjVOaHzLKWMk1g7at1zAPgSZbKAtTaJ/P0kvRFhD/VSrhOOXLpFfWYZI/1Al@FkYvm3XOxZVIxl/gyyRPmcmV@I65CyQp2H6cr0pgLVfioF2kzg4xnDUVLtqyX8FEUTAo/RsWlnyCvVFZATh8MvH23P/95CWVGsQzSUkQmGKSOAnnP6YxbhrQE0cBFVhbK8pViaNDmzcWZC71fIwAky0suURjF8XxyASgnZr4qeq2cecyEvXBQ2A36BGEZkTkFAaTFXZGmEPtyxXoY3@Ec7M3IsDmDoFeh4VkDJV@tixEGd08gbCoAdsJdKWVEz@cb65bA1P@6G4/x6/WHeO7FOZ6JpA8f@sN66Yy@nvkdR/i9xO/rr7tLfJ/i8/mU2PH9An/P8HuO34mhjS8q8UibjPtDgy77ZrhwTiK@Yqqwna5it1oxDJIo7N4NwLzn3pys2c52nJq60NTFAfVWU29rahPbMta1QIGPaH7QFYGJUD5mBU8FoiENYpacwH8YPPiigCx9sBOXuQL1CC18DB10ko1HnBDu77VT7YXbD/iq77gH9NuK3piUvPGwDkUQVr/Ji3mIWAhTEXFSQAEqgYeASDHz/IKrJWdRj9R/x3jMxcpe5LKwE39nC3fsOA6GFT6xhyIVfYUFAsteZEVsCaGifTtnZhEs@BJ2V/MxzDDnSilgrKnKZI9t706wOtyjv1fF2naGnnN6OnE0mNJytQY/Q7/sOOYF@YigamTT2WwXYlXS4h7WPGbwRZbMHEqfAo9QzRsdaO9OT9VQ0RH7dHs3ooOrtaHXrKLyaj4vZlAprywrS7hAHmMkOSN0E3d67rlkDpZ2lERQwBXc5V0OBps6Aq8HxDsMBsHVdEAb0P3S54phhlCaMJZRF8B3DEMP/f7A@liFVnUXocIEdyTDJW7MZCyrQmlUIf@dpBVJK7q8yLmdkVkTSxqVidOYJ412NonRlk8ozM1BvilNeCAFSQ49UxtxywikblQYlKgMde1Io6iuZDGGgzqagADC1MhAxXYVIyqB@mJT6Wiql0I8MS/9CA/nhD8xwlLGo5KZRpVCprcluK3SMdV9jTTBrCp4hk0NebcMVgibrGUjOG5WWpMGkJLiop@W@HT3ra5e2DF8yTHzZrhQNeSYK22ksWXph3iy0oYcwg4FLDmmVe07TPOqKEeEVdO@@F/4VuAhsU5BJmUqG6wZYfKKnEPiMh5uUJxgD9XBJqpWt@Yew32DXbSu6X72mRs4T7csdcO0ubvDIuPNIJDM3@xtkzCYA98jLakx3PFv3Swhtf0dqS1Zkm6ZrnG6Y9e66yZuHTQM8jOBugOI7g4CoBzKTkIaPjLJj3nxqN3YQsfAJlW0gkWwUAd8I9xLXg3XDP9iXCO@5YoHXMvCMJ3BBfwGngfeGXj48BomZ09kEECPn4kSQ5p7cLDzQRUyFSvIFCujOhlQpyfilE/QQhclT5doAMHiGpQ8LkboKK24dSyEmet53sX55fnZBYVSO4Y6SOhKN0MKloKGlhzQqsnIzpynKHpJAyh1r07qPTFDowIXOAWTcsZWrLCXzhF59PlOxcjocXrKBxNU5ug@tO17C8t/HIPv9xe0XlXnzG0BRug3UyLqYbVoPj3twnl5YuBqc@zT@9n8gbI5I1AcS1g8Cg@oS4tnTiiR1J0uMSjYHMxa1QOM2aV2f/gqww4QpAVGNYL3f36eAS5AlOoWjC0vXJtO0OEvX03QI8iW@YKHyEAZxLZM9KwuGkpXdhP6iGX5c5blrupYJo3220PL8mcs27q5tiw/tAwXfm3Z9sCy7XHLtq7qWlYf/mKet6yZZsUUjan95M0M3OL8YC9ppZeebM07W/ODrQyd0rlq2PnIQ7cP7HK0dV7JAb07w20tkb3S7Xg@L43DX@n1@Xzb8dS72y8zeNBlo6MKmc1cw9xxEKvV6bRa3HTIl/8dvpz49IwwyGt@8SbUmoo3Scss9A1BYfWNm4PE3gg3n@MQ1GWoTqtuAQ3X3njb0a6diJc@j3F/VFUL5qJ/zUhzOjHedbrCQjfSwjraRuyJMGopkQmFFeXmhURZOT8MJ5UlHDz@5BsGNMvT1FkW5hqDMw5hs3PJxh2YIiu81@upA18nzchBw5aRUGOZLhg7hyA/bsrXzown5qU33o17w93dZPbNqi8WQl8stGTRXjdYS2UtNWqpUUvNWmrWUvOWmnckZK2EzmZyWk3u7Cb31TK4ufV8phU9RtE/PrAzZCyhNpGYe3vgK3Z5Xl/cMe5pxDREiPeGC93icfx6u/h04sH761uzBy8i2sG@Eh55sXBrL1PdMn6tvWyrK28y7XShyrl2cXU1/aGckyKtrkuT6ro03DUzoq32rya/Ie6m1hMp4910/EMeE6VammzF17qT10SlWpNx8zGCV7CVHmZN3uA4HcV0EaunVJwId3hD5QLviQxKvC4YUZTH/jblVTGfQT/J/upDGnxnIYkhceAXWPMRxQz6tXL9rk21VyeuEdqasJ/l6Iqh11wxa5uk8hEOW7wfMkzGzM3dKHOj3EVEzI6dcj51a1eMnWHrleaRtY9R@5i1j3lnQ4ccdegNHK9v9hGEcPy7Cge9r2JEn39e//7xk766f779@O@3X67hj@v/6pWvojfsgNj@P/5whkFP811/ev@cvDrxf63oCVY5PNXul8VyNKVw/Pz5Pw) (revised 2020-06-13).

---

¹ For deterministic schemes, there can be a few more forbidden signatures, depending on message. That's because when $R=S$ the method described won't work. However, exhibiting a concrete example would be a break of the hash.

Comment: I guess this rules out creating a signature using the **same** key pair of course; choosing the modulus $N$ - and thus primes $p$ and $q$ - seems orthogonal to such a requirement (which is not stated in the question). I guess such a scheme would break the signature requirements to begin with, as there would be two messages matching the same signature.